# В Visual Studio Code при отладке выдает Waiting for the debugger to disconnect

Tags: node.js, отладка, visual-studio-code

В Visual Studio Code при отладке после обновления node до версии 9.10.1 теперь получаю

```
node --inspect-brk=38580 objects.js 
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:38580/d023d818-10f5-4499-b1d0-a30b4e1af713
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

Настройки launch.json

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
        {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/objects.js"
    }
]
}
```

Переустанавливал VSCode - не помогло.

Кто сталкивался с подобным? Как это побороть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил этот вопрос. Оставлю решение здесь, может пригодится кому.

Нужно указать путь до node в свойстве "runtimeExecutable". Я node ставил через nvm, поэтому вышло так:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Program",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/objects.js",
    "runtimeExecutable": "/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v9.10.1/bin/node",
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто перезагрузить VSCode. У меня никаких json не было.. хотя я случайно создал, потом удалил, потом при каждом запуске видел сообщение detach чего то там... потом код, потом ниже сообщение. Сразу нашёл как решается на англоязычном форуме, стеке точнее. Перезагрузка. Там что нор всё должно работать.